# Change background of a webpage permanently from chrome inspector

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools

There is one application that really bothers me and my eyes hurt for seing a very bold red background color for the body. I want to change that and want the change to stay even after page refresh. Is there such a thing ? Is there an add-on or chrome plugin or anything that does this job ?

I know how to change the bg color from inspector but that disappears with page refresh.

Comment: see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8NjLMJu_DM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow a link below and read instruction how to change and apply user-defined styles for web-pages.
https://www.itsupportguides.com/computer-accessibility/how-to-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-with-google-chrome/